# Trouble recoloring bars in ggplot2 based on color names in a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to recolor bars on a bar graph based on certain conditions of the values. (are they positive or negative? are they above or below the threshold?). Because I have do to **a lot** of these plots, I thought the easiest way to do that would be to create a column with the colors I want the bars to be, based on those conditions. This was easy enough with a few ifelse statements. But now, the problem is that ggplot won't pull those colors in the correct order. I have tried several different ways of doing this and can't seem to get it right.

Here is an mock-up of dataframe filtered for just the first location we want to graph, with some example data. I have provided the full dput at the bottom so you can reproduce the full example yourself.

```
     species  location test_residuals species_order           color
1   species2 location1     -2.1121481             1     dodgerblue1
2   species1 location1     -1.4315793             2      lightblue1
3   species8 location1      0.3727298             3 lightgoldenrod1
4   species3 location1     -5.2163387             4     dodgerblue1
5   species6 location1      3.5301076             5      goldenrod1
6   species4 location1     -0.7546595             6      lightblue1
7  species10 location1     -0.1857843             7      lightblue1
8  species12 location1     -0.5199749             8      lightblue1
9   species7 location1     -2.1884659             9     dodgerblue1
10 species13 location1      4.7223194            10      goldenrod1
11 species11 location1      0.3374291            11 lightgoldenrod1
12  species9 location1      0.6245307            12 lightgoldenrod1
13  species5 location1     -0.3676778            13      lightblue1
```

when I try this

```
test.plot.1<- data1 %>% 
  filter(location == "location1") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    reorder(x = species, species_order), 
    y= test_residuals, 
    fill = species)) +
  geom_bar( stat= "identity") +
  ggtitle("Location 1") +
  theme_pubclean(
    base_size = 14 )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "none") +  
  xlab("") + ylab("Pearson Residuals") + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_abline(intercept = -2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color)
```

I get the error " Error in is_missing(values) : object 'color' not found"

If I instead specify the dataframe with:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = data1$color)
```

I don't get an error, and the color pallet is even correct, but the bars themselves are not the correct color!

[image: miscolored graph]

I also get miscolored bars if I specify another vector in fill (for example color) produces this:
[image: another miscolored graph]

I thought perhaps this was because when you have to specify the dataframe with "data1$color" the filter function was no longer applicable so I broke down by pipe and created a data frame that was pre-filtered to call for the ggplot. But even when this data frame is ordered with arrange the bars are still not the correct color.

```
test.plot.df2<- data1 %>% 
  filter(location == "location1") %>% 
  arrange(species_order) 

test.plot.2<- test.plot.df2 %>% 
ggplot(aes(
  reorder(x = species, species_order), 
  y= test_residuals, 
  fill = species)) +
  geom_bar( stat= "identity") +
  ggtitle("Location 1") +
  theme_pubclean(
    base_size = 14 )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "none") +  
  xlab("") + ylab("Pearson Residuals") + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_abline(intercept = -2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values =  test.plot.df2$color)

test.plot.2
```

Produces:

[image: another, differently miscolored graph]

I must have a syntax error somewhere, but I cannot seem to find the logic behind the order of column colors produced, and am thus unable to work out how to correct said syntax error. Among (many many) things I have tried, I created a single vector to call for color

```
test.plot.df2<- data1 %>% 
  filter(location == "location1") %>% 
  arrange(species_order) 

test_color1<- test.plot.df2$color

test.plot.2<- test.plot.df2 %>% 
ggplot(aes(
  reorder(x = species, species_order), 
  y= test_residuals, 
  fill = species)) +
  geom_bar( stat= "identity") +
  ggtitle("Location 1") +
  theme_pubclean(
    base_size = 14 )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "none") +  
  xlab("") + ylab("Pearson Residuals") + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_abline(intercept = -2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values =  test_color1)

test.plot.2
```

Which produces the same graph as above. I have also tried creating a new column, with species order as a character, and calling that for fill. This once again produces a miscolored graph:

```
test.plot.df3<- data1 %>% 
  filter(location == "location1") %>% 
  arrange(species_order) %>% 
  mutate(species_order_character = as.character(species_order))

test.plot.3<- test.plot.df3 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    reorder(x = species, species_order), 
    y= test_residuals, 
    fill = species_order_character)) +
  geom_bar( stat= "identity") +
  ggtitle("Location 1") +
  theme_pubclean(
    base_size = 14 )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "none") +  
  xlab("") + ylab("Pearson Residuals") + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_abline(intercept = -2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = test.plot.df3$color)

test.plot.3
```

[image: another, differently miscolored graph]

I am at my wits end. I know for each graph I could manually enter the colors like so :

```
test.plot.4<-data1 %>% 
  filter(location == "location1") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    reorder(x = species, species_order), 
    y= test_residuals, 
    fill = color)) +
  geom_bar( stat= "identity") +
  ggtitle("Location 1") +
  theme_pubclean(
    base_size = 14 )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "none") +  
  xlab("") + ylab("Pearson Residuals") + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_abline(intercept = -2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "dodgerblue1","goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1"))

test.plot.4
```

[image: a correctly colored graph]

This produces a correctly colored graph, but 1) I would like to have to avoid doing this by hand for each of the many times I have to reproduce this for different locations and different data sets, and 2) even here I can't figure out why the colors need to be ordered that way (ie.: "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "lightgoldenrod1", "lightblue1") to correspond to the correct levels.

Anyone have any insights on what is happening here, and how i might be able to correct my syntax so that I can just call the colors directly from the data frame?

Thanks very much below is the full code to reproduce my data frame :

```
data1 <- as.data.frame(structure(list(species = c(
  "species1", "species1", "species1",
  "species1", "species1", "species1", "species2", "species2", "species2",
  "species2", "species2", "species2", "species3", "species3", "species3",
  "species3", "species3", "species3", "species4", "species4", "species4",
  "species4", "species4", "species4", "species5", "species5", "species5",
  "species5", "species5", "species5", "species6", "species6", "species6",
  "species6", "species6", "species6", "species7", "species7", "species7",
  "species7", "species7", "species7", "species8", "species8", "species8",
  "species8", "species8", "species8", "species9", "species9", "species9",
  "species9", "species9", "species9", "species10", "species10",
  "species10", "species10", "species10", "species10", "species11",
  "species11", "species11", "species11", "species11", "species11",
  "species12", "species12", "species12", "species12", "species12",
  "species12", "species13", "species13", "species13", "species13",
  "species13", "species13"
), location = c(
  "location1", "location2",
  "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1",
  "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6",
  "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5",
  "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4",
  "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3",
  "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2",
  "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1",
  "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6",
  "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5",
  "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4",
  "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3",
  "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2",
  "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1",
  "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6",
  "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5",
  "location6"
), test_residuals = c(
  -1.43157930150306, -0.314316453493008,
  -0.695141335636191, -2.50279485833503, 15.9593244074832, -3.33654341630138,
  -2.11214812519871, -0.754659543030408, -2.3490433970076, -1.7153639945355,
  19.798140868747, -3.92267054433899, -5.21633871800811, -2.78600907892934,
  4.13596459214836, -2.35842831236716, -4.34026196885217, 8.57347502255589,
  -0.754659543030408, -2.11214812519871, -1.7153639945355, 9.81355206430024,
  -0.0987450246067016, -2.3490433970076, -0.367677794665814, -0.298606543279543,
  -0.261519516774949, -0.131369364295332, -0.472983769840402, 0.781602686808182,
  3.53010760821268, -5.58101185979998, -5.5626379561955, 5.74088803484089,
  -12.2995673766017, 10.0851562256946, -2.18846593288851, -0.161746935435626,
  -1.76434843091121, -1.28043017699489, 9.27256034587805, -4.25159798465366,
  0.372729803108757, -1.46533093179302, 0.229469416155288, 6.81036162101337,
  -2.23476643015094, 0.351490912112304, 0.624530722145124, 1.07723113193857,
  -0.262738728590663, -0.945967539680804, 3.3007673589212, -1.36569858688998,
  -0.18578433666679, -0.519974923799824, -0.422293423319278, 5.03783441267317,
  -0.965694731846794, -0.668900062090651, 0.337429125033733, -0.656846821476658,
  -0.250681398015413, -0.153477341599593, -1.30759758387474, 0.686219077483926,
  -0.519974923799824, -0.18578433666679, -0.668900062090651, -0.422293423319278,
  -0.36984444744839, 1.10535312007138, 4.72231943431065, 0.0138571578271046,
  5.16352940820454, -4.08311797265573, -1.90430067033424, 0.0153780833066176
), species_order = c(
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 13L,
  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
  9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L,
  12L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L,
  8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
), color = c(
  "lightblue1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1",
  "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "goldenrod1",
  "dodgerblue1", "dodgerblue1", "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1",
  "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "lightgoldenrod1", "lightblue1",
  "lightgoldenrod1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "lightgoldenrod1", "lightgoldenrod1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "lightgoldenrod1", "goldenrod1", "lightgoldenrod1", "goldenrod1",
  "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -78L
)))
```

Comment: Try `scale_fill_identity(guide=guide_legend())` if you want to use color names stored in a column of your data.frame. And the `guide=` is needed to add a legend in case that's needed. Otherwise remove it.

Comment: Are the bars to be stacked?  There's more than one color value per species in your data.

Comment: No the bars aren't going to be stacked, I am going to build a different graph for each location, so there will only be one species per graph. The color values are based on the test_residuals: >2 should be the bold yellow ("goldenrod1"), < -2 should be the bold blue ( "dodgerblue1"), positive but <2 should be the light yellow ("lightgoldenrod1"), and negative but > -2 should be the light blue ( "lightblue1").

Comment: Thanks stefan! this is exactly what I was looking for and worked beautifully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've calculated the colour explicitly in your dataframe you can use `scale_fill_identity`. The only other change is that fill is taken from column `color` not `species`. The you get:

```
test.plot.2<- test.plot.df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    reorder(x = species, species_order), 
    y= test_residuals, 
    fill = color)) +
  geom_bar( stat= "identity") +
  ggtitle("Location 1") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "none") +  
  xlab("") + ylab("Pearson Residuals") + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  geom_abline(intercept = -2, slope = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  scale_fill_identity()

test.plot.2
```

[image: Output plot]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I think you want `fill = color` instead of `fill = species`.  Then you can construct the values to `scale_fill_manual` from this vector by setting names.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- as.data.frame(structure(list(species = c(
  "species1", "species1", "species1",
  "species1", "species1", "species1", "species2", "species2", "species2",
  "species2", "species2", "species2", "species3", "species3", "species3",
  "species3", "species3", "species3", "species4", "species4", "species4",
  "species4", "species4", "species4", "species5", "species5", "species5",
  "species5", "species5", "species5", "species6", "species6", "species6",
  "species6", "species6", "species6", "species7", "species7", "species7",
  "species7", "species7", "species7", "species8", "species8", "species8",
  "species8", "species8", "species8", "species9", "species9", "species9",
  "species9", "species9", "species9", "species10", "species10",
  "species10", "species10", "species10", "species10", "species11",
  "species11", "species11", "species11", "species11", "species11",
  "species12", "species12", "species12", "species12", "species12",
  "species12", "species13", "species13", "species13", "species13",
  "species13", "species13"
), location = c(
  "location1", "location2",
  "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1",
  "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6",
  "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5",
  "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4",
  "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3",
  "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2",
  "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1",
  "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6",
  "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5",
  "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4",
  "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2", "location3",
  "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1", "location2",
  "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6", "location1",
  "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5", "location6",
  "location1", "location2", "location3", "location4", "location5",
  "location6"
), test_residuals = c(
  -1.43157930150306, -0.314316453493008,
  -0.695141335636191, -2.50279485833503, 15.9593244074832, -3.33654341630138,
  -2.11214812519871, -0.754659543030408, -2.3490433970076, -1.7153639945355,
  19.798140868747, -3.92267054433899, -5.21633871800811, -2.78600907892934,
  4.13596459214836, -2.35842831236716, -4.34026196885217, 8.57347502255589,
  -0.754659543030408, -2.11214812519871, -1.7153639945355, 9.81355206430024,
  -0.0987450246067016, -2.3490433970076, -0.367677794665814, -0.298606543279543,
  -0.261519516774949, -0.131369364295332, -0.472983769840402, 0.781602686808182,
  3.53010760821268, -5.58101185979998, -5.5626379561955, 5.74088803484089,
  -12.2995673766017, 10.0851562256946, -2.18846593288851, -0.161746935435626,
  -1.76434843091121, -1.28043017699489, 9.27256034587805, -4.25159798465366,
  0.372729803108757, -1.46533093179302, 0.229469416155288, 6.81036162101337,
  -2.23476643015094, 0.351490912112304, 0.624530722145124, 1.07723113193857,
  -0.262738728590663, -0.945967539680804, 3.3007673589212, -1.36569858688998,
  -0.18578433666679, -0.519974923799824, -0.422293423319278, 5.03783441267317,
  -0.965694731846794, -0.668900062090651, 0.337429125033733, -0.656846821476658,
  -0.250681398015413, -0.153477341599593, -1.30759758387474, 0.686219077483926,
  -0.519974923799824, -0.18578433666679, -0.668900062090651, -0.422293423319278,
  -0.36984444744839, 1.10535312007138, 4.72231943431065, 0.0138571578271046,
  5.16352940820454, -4.08311797265573, -1.90430067033424, 0.0153780833066176
), species_order = c(
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
  1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 13L,
  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
  9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L,
  12L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L,
  8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
), color = c(
  "lightblue1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1",
  "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "goldenrod1",
  "dodgerblue1", "dodgerblue1", "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1",
  "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "dodgerblue1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "lightgoldenrod1", "lightblue1",
  "lightgoldenrod1", "goldenrod1", "dodgerblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "lightgoldenrod1", "lightgoldenrod1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "goldenrod1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1",
  "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1", "lightblue1",
  "lightgoldenrod1", "goldenrod1", "lightgoldenrod1", "goldenrod1",
  "dodgerblue1", "lightblue1", "lightgoldenrod1"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -78L
))) %>% 
  as_tibble()

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(color = str_remove(color, "1"))

df %>%
  ggplot() + 
  aes(species, test_residuals, fill = color) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = set_names(unique(df$color), unique(df$color))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~location, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have worked, the bars do not correspond to their assigned colors here. For instance location 1 species one should have a light blue bar, while location 1, species 2 should have a light blue bar and so on...

Comment: that facet wrap is a cool move though!

Comment: You're right - sorry about that.  I fixed it.